# SQL recordset confusing results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a leaderboards for my game which displays the top rankers by map in PHP from a mySQl database;

```
SELECT name, time, MAX(score) as max_score 
FROM leaderboards 
WHERE name != '' AND hidden=0 AND map='" .$currMap. "' AND score > 0 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY score DESC, time ASC LIMIT ".($get_page*10).", 10
```

I'm paging the results shown on the site in 10s.

Theres are several people on there who have multiple scores. Their records don't show up where they should on the list. Instead they shows up way further down in POSITION of their lowest score, but with the VALUE of their highest. So it's not sorting them correctly.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried `... ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC, time ASC ...` ?

Comment: do hidden and map attributes for this 2900 score guy are ok (qualificable in the query) ?

Comment: @EugenRieck I don't think we can use aggregate functions with order by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not pulling up the time associated with that score.  It is pulling up an arbitrary record.  Your query is using a MySQL extension, where you have a column in the `select` (`time`) that is not in the `group by`.  As *explicitly` stated in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html), you get a value from an indeterminate row.

One way you can get what you want is with the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT name,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(time ORDER BY score DESC), ',', 1) as TimeAtMaxScore,
       MAX(score) as max_score 
FROM leaderboards 
WHERE name <> '' AND hidden = 0 AND map='" .$currMap. "' AND score > 0 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY score DESC, time ASC LIMIT ".($get_page*10).", 10;
```

(As a note:  I used version 5.6 of the documentation, because it is more explicit about what happens.  [Version 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) does a better job of explaining what functional dependency is, which is the basis for this extension.  The ANSI standard does allow it under some circumstances.)

EDIT:

You have the same problem in the `order by`.  You can do:

```
ORDER BY max_score DESC, TimeAtMaxScore ASC
LIMIT . . .
```

Comment: Its still not pulling certain records. If a single one of a users five submitted scores has say hidden=1 does that mean he won't be included all together? Or just not that record? If I remove the GROUP BY he shows up

Comment: @user1022585 . . . Every name that passes the `where` clause will appear (on a single row) in the `group by`.  Try removing the `limit`.

Comment: I removed the limit, the missing players name shows up right at the bottom, in position of his lowest score, but with the value of his highest